# Matlab dir('*.txt') command is not listing txt files in order

Tags: matlab, directory, directory-listing, lexicographic

I am reading text files from a folder using `dir('*.txt')` in MATLAB. Text files are named `0, 4, 8, 12, ..180.txt`. `dir` returns `0` first, then `100`, then `104` and so on. Why is this happening?

Comment: This is just how lexicographical ordering works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) works by looking only at the information that is required to make a decision. The information, in our case, is the ASCII value of the characters in filenames. Consider the following examples:

- If we have two files names `10.txt` and `2.txt`, the listing mechanism will compare the 1<sup>st</sup> character of these files, i.e. `1` vs. `2`, and will return whichever is smallest, which in this case is the `1` that belongs to `10.txt`.
- If instead we had `2.txt` and `20.txt`, the first character is the same, so the next character will be compared, which is either `.` or `0`. Here, since the ASCII value of `.` is `46` and of `0` is `48`, `2.txt` will be returned first.

You can solve this by always having the maximum number of digits you need for the filenames, meaning:

```
0.txt    -->  000.txt
4.txt    -->  004.txt
25.txt   -->  025.txt
180.txt  -->  180.txt
```

Then files will be returned in the expected order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sensitive to the order of files **and** you already know their names, you don't have to use `dir` at all:

```
for ii=0:4:180
    filename = sprintf('%d.txt', ii);
    fid = fopen( fullfile('/path/to', filename), 'r' );
    % ... do the processing here
    fclose(fid);
end
```